# Back button not remembering choices in Javascript quiz

Tags: javascript

I need help on the following code, I created a back button in my Javascript Quiz, but if I click on it, it goes back but does not remember the choices i chose thereby forcing me to choose a new answer. I don't know how to go about this. Below is the Javascript  Link: 
http://jsbin.com/zinagipovo/edit?html,css,js,console

```
var currentQuestion = 0;
var score = 0;
var totQuestions = questions.length;

var container = document.getElementById('quizContainer');
var questionEl = document.getElementById('question');
var opt1 = document.getElementById('opt1');
var opt2 = document.getElementById('opt2');
var opt3 = document.getElementById('opt3');
var opt4 = document.getElementById('opt4');
var backButton = document.getElementById('backButton');
var nextButton = document.getElementById('nextButton');
var resultCont = document.getElementById('result');

function loadQuestion (questionIndex) {
    var q = questions[questionIndex];
    questionEl.textContent = (questionIndex + 1) + '. ' +q.question;
    opt1.textContent = q.option1;
    opt2.textContent = q.option2;
    opt3.textContent = q.option3;
    opt4.textContent = q.option4;
};


function loadNextQuestion () {
    var selectedOption = 
document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked');
    if(!selectedOption){
        alert('Please select your answer!');
        return;
}

var answer = selectedOption.value;
if(questions[currentQuestion].answer == answer){
    score +=1;
}
selectedOption.checked = false;
currentQuestion++;
if(currentQuestion == totQuestions - 1){
    nextButton.textContent = 'Finish';
}
if (currentQuestion == totQuestions){
    resultCont.style.display = '';
    resultCont.textContent = 'You got ' + score +' questions correct';
    return false;
    currentQuestion = 0;
}
loadQuestion(currentQuestion);
}

function loadPrevQuestion () {

    if (currentQuestion > 0) {
        currentQuestion--;
        loadQuestion(currentQuestion);
}

}

loadQuestion(currentQuestion);
```

The questions are in an external file

```
    var questions = [{
    "question": "How many long vowels do we have in English Language?",
    "option1": "10",
    "option2": "5",
    "option3": "6",
    "option4": "7",
    "answer": "2"
}, {
    "question": "How many short vowels do we have in English Language?",
    "option1": "6",
    "option2": "5",
    "option3": "12",
    "option4": "7", 
    "answer": "4"
}, {
    "question": "How many Vowels do we have in English Language?",
    "option1": "20",
    "option2": "24",
    "option3": "8",
    "option4": "12",
    "answer": "1"
},  {
    "question":"Which of these is not a Vowel Sound?",
    "option1": "/θ/",
    "option2": "/əʊ/",
    "option3": "/i:/",
    "option4": "/u:/",
    "answer": "1"
}, 

]
```

The HTML Code goes thus:

```
    <div>
    <button id="quiz" onclick="document.getElementById('quizContainer').style.display='block'" style="width:auto; margin-top: 15px;">Take the Quiz!!</button>

    <div id="quizContainer" class="modal">
    <span onclick="document.getElementById('quizContainer').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Quiz">×</span>
        <header class="title">Vowel Sounds</header>
        <div id="question" class="question"></div>
        <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="1" /> <span id="opt1"></span></label>
        <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="2" /> <span id="opt2"></span></label>
        <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="3" /> <span id="opt3"></span></label>
        <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="4" /> <span id="opt4"></span></label>
        <button id="nextButton" class="next-btn" onclick="loadNextQuestion();">Next</button>
        <button id="backButton" class="back-btn" onclick="loadPrevQuestion();">Back</button>
        <div id="result" class="container result" style="display:none;"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('quizContainer');
    </script>
```

The CSS code is:

```
    .modal { display: none; background-color: #fefefe; height: 387px; width: 100%; position: fixed; z-index: 1; overflow: auto; padding-top: 100px; margin-top: 100px; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);  padding: 20px; border: 1px solid #08038C; box-shadow: 0 0 8px 3px #fff; }
    .title { padding-top: 20px; text-align: center; font-size: 40px; text-transform: uppercase; color: #08038c; }
    .question { padding: 20px; font-size: 22px; background: #08038c; border-radius: 20px; margin: 10px 0 10px 0; color: #f6f6f6; }
    .option{ width: 450px; display: inline-block; padding: 10px 0 10px 15px; vertical-align: middle; background: #08038c; margin: 10px 0 10px 10px; color: white; border-radius: 20px; }
    .option:hover{  background: #08038c; color: #f6f6f6;}
    .next-btn, .back-btn { border: 2px solid #08038c; outline: none;    background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5); width: 150px; height: 35px; cursor: pointer; float: right;  margin: 10px; }
    .next-btn:hover, .back-btn:hover { background: #08038c; color: #f6f6f6; }
    .result { height: 20px; text-align: center; font-size: 20px; }
    .option input:checked .option{ background: #08038c; color: #000; }
    .close { position: absolute; right: 35px; top: 15px; color: #000; font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold; }
    #quiz { background-color: #4CAF50; color: white; padding: 14px 20px; margin: 8px 0; border: none; cursor: pointer; width: 100%; }
    .back-btn { float:left;}
    .close:hover, .close:focus { color: red; cursor: pointer; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the jsbin's JavaScript. You define `totQuestions` before you define `questions`. If you move it to after your program at least runs.

The general idea should be to store the answers and calculate the total at the end. You can simply create another array, `answers`, and in `loadNextQuestion`, set `answers[currentQuestion] = answer` instead of your if/score += 1 block. You can add similar functionality to `loadPrevQuestion`. Then in loadQuestion, you would set `checked` of the option corresponding to `answers[currentQuestion]`. Finally, instead of the `score` variable, you'd calculate it at the end, such as by a [reduction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

[Here's a jsbin doing the above](http://jsbin.com/tiyohihose/1/edit?html,js,console,output), though it's using ES6 and instead of an `answers` array I melded it into `questions` and made the options dynamic.